# UserForm search date value as string on a excel sheet but its not matching the value to the date column in the sheet

Tags: excel, vba, string, date, search

I have a VBA user form where the user searches different values in a database excel sheet. This search value (string) can have different types of data ranging from text, date, number etc. When the user searches for a date like "31-12-2020" as a string value it cannot match the dates in that "Visit Date" column. Can anybody help me where am I going wrong.

```
'My code below to check if the search value is the date

Dim iExpression As String
Dim sOutput As Boolean
    
iExpression = frmForm.txtSearch.Value
sOutput = IsDate(iExpression)
   
If sOutput = True Then
    sValue = Format(frmForm.txtSearch.Value, "DD-MM-YYYY") 
Else
    'do nothing
End If

iColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sColumn, shDatabase.Range("A1:M1"), 0)
    
'Remove the filter from Database worksheet
If shDatabase.FilterMode = True Then
    shDatabase.AutoFilterMode = False
End If

'Apply filter on Database worksheet
If frmForm.cmbSearchColumn.Value = "Visitor Id" Then
    shDatabase.Range("A1:M" & iDatabaseRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:=sValue
Else
    If frmForm.cmbSearchColumn.Value = "Visit Date" Then
        ' here even if the search value is found but below its not matching inside the column
        shDatabase.Range("A1:L" & iDatabaseRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:=sValue
    Else
        shDatabase.Range("A1:M" & iDatabaseRow).AutoFilter Field:=iColumn, Criteria1:="*" & sValue & "*"
    End If
```

Comment: `iColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sColumn, shDatabase.Range("A1:M1"), 0)` You search for sColumn but `sValue = Format(frmForm.txtSearch.Value, "DD-MM-YYYY")` or is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: well i was playing around with the format code just to see if maybe the format I was passing was the problem but it wasn't so the code is still there it's redundant

Comment: If the code you posted is not the correct code then replace it so that we can see what the issue is. As it is now, I'd call it a typo. `sColumn <> sValue`

Comment: The issue is if your column has real dates (numeric dates) then they don't match strings. Therefore your search value should be of type `date` or `double` to make it work. Try `Criteria1:=cDbl(cDate(sValue))`

Comment: thanks @Andreas it worked like a charm your first suggestion. you're the man!
I have another bug if I pass a numeric value it's not matching as well its just a number like "3333" but with another column like visitor ID which is numeric as well its working fine but not with the other column.